# Access Control for API requests is not working in WSO2 APIM 4.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, rate-limiting, wso2-enterprise-integrator, whitelist

I am trying [rate limiting - allowed ip operation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/rate-limiting/access-control/) in WSO2 APIM 4.1.0.

Steps followed:

- Added new Policy by navigate to `Advanced Policies` Under the `Rate Limiting Policies` option in admin portal.

[image: added policy]

- Conditional Group added by selecting Specific IP option (in below pic i just given dummy value on behalf of original ip due to security reason)

[image: specified ip]

- Engage policy with API in publisher portal

[image: publisher portal]

Problem:

- Set Request Count as 5, it is allowing to hit API Continuously even though rate limit exceed(more than 5 hit).
- if i provide any invalid ip under conditional policy, still API is accessible. I think whatever ip i have provided those are only having access and rate limit applied to that IP.

Kindly clarify on the same..

Comment: After attaching the advanced policy to the API, did you deploy a new API revision?

Comment: Hi @WasuraWattearachchi
Thank you so much for your reply.
After engage policy with api in publisher portal, By using  life cycle option i published with the same version, not with new version. do i need to deploy as new version?

Comment: No worries. Yes. If you do any runtime-specific change to an API/API Product, you need to deploy a new revision from APIM 4.0.0 onwards so that those changes will be reflected through the specified gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested above by both @Athiththan and @Wasura Wattearachchi  , I have deployed new revision after applying policy to API, which resolves my usecase.

Policy:

[image: policy]

[image: invertcondition]

As depicted above policy diagram, 2 request is allowed from specific ip by passing `X-Forwarded-For` in header section when invoke api. from 3rd request onwards it is blocking the api call and getting below response.

```
{
    "code": "900802",
    "message": "Message throttled out",
    "description": "You have exceeded your quota .You can access API after 2022-May-22 10:45:00+0000 UTC",
    "nextAccessTime": "2022-May-22 10:45:00+0000 UTC"
}
```

Note: if i pass invalid ip in header section, atleast one time api hit happening which is expected behavior in APIM Gateway

Answer (score 1):

It is required to publish a new revision of the API from the Publisher portal if we are making any changes to the existing one. Hence, if you are engaging a new API Level policy after publishing the API, deploy a new revision of the API from the Publisher portal and select appropriate Gateway Environments to deploy the updated API.

Answering your questions (problems)

> 1. `Set Request Count as 5, it is allowing to hit API Continuously even though rate limit exceed(more than 5 hit)`

Deploy a new Revision of the API and try-out the scenario. As I explained
above, we have to deploy a new revision of the API to get the updated configurations deployed in selected Environments

> 2. `if i provide any invalid ip under conditional policy, still API is accessible. I think whatever ip i have provided those are only having access and rate limit applied to that IP.`

At first, deploy a new revision of the API to get the updated configurations deployed.

As per the shared screenshots, the Advanced Policy is configured to throttle after 5 requests/min in both conditions; When the conditional group is not met, and when the conditions are met. For demo purposes, you can the threshold count of either one and try out the scenario.

As per your throttling policy, if a client invokes the respective API from the `192.168.0.0` IP, it will throttle after 5 requests, as well as, if any from other IPs invoke, they'll also be throttled after 5 requests.

Also, note to test the scenarios, you can send the desired IP address under `X-Forwarded-For` header while you are invoking the API from your local machine because the blocking and whitelisting happens based on the value received via mentioned header. If the header is not present, then the client IP is extracted from the request.